# Slick slider свайп не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Всем привет.

Есть slick-slider на странице целых 4 .

Проблема  очень экстрординарная так как все слайдеры работают кроме 3-го.У всех прописан один и тот же стиль

```
$(function(){
    try
    {
        $( 'section.cinema .slider, section.news .slider, section.shopping .slider, section.restaurants .slider' ).slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            centerMode: false,
            variableWidth: true,
            swipe:true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 400,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 768,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },

                {
                    breakpoint: 1140,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
    catch( $e ){}
});
```

1. `section.cinema .slider,`
2. `section.news .slider`
3. `section.shopping .slider` слайдер которое не работает
4. `section.restaurants .slider`

Третий работает только стрелками а swipe не работает.У других все работает.
Очень прошу помогите.

Мои попытки.

1.Вместо  `$( 'section.cinema .slider, section.news .slider, section.shopping .slider, section.restaurants .slider' ).` этого проста написать `$(.slider' ).`

2.Изменить версию слайдера я поставил **1.8.0** также **1.9.0** тоже не помогло

3.Также добавить для каждого класса свою функцию слайдера тоже не помогло

Правка.

Я пробовал добавить версию **1.5.9** тогда свайп работал только один раз

Ссылка на слайдер **[slick](http://ganjamall.gq/en)**

Comment: Это в каком браузере у вас не работает?

Comment: @EVG во всех.Подключил версию 1.5.9 slick-а начал работать первый раз менялсья норм а потом только менялись через два блока.То есть чтобы поменять надо было взять блок и тащить его пока 2 ой блок с лева или с права не будет полностью видимым.Также при подключении этой вышеупомянутый версии начали глючить другие слайдеры находящийся в этой странице.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А не работает всё потому-что разная ширина слайдов, у всех остальных слайдеров всё в `display:block` + `img` и соответственно `variableWidth` параметр отрабатывает верно, а в 3-м варианте `background-image` + `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Это те изменения которые вам необходимо ввести для корректной работы в css и scripts.min.js . На 3-м слайдеры стоит `display:flex` , скиньте его в 
 `display:block`, в целом flex не нужен и уж если используешь flex то `flex-wrap:wrap` в слайдере не должно быть, элементы в 3 ряда падают. Также убираем `variableWidth: true`. Тестируйте, у меня всё завелось.

```js
$(function () {
    try {
        $("section.cinema .slider, section.news .slider, section.restaurants .slider").slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            centerMode: false,
            variableWidth: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            draggable: true,
            touchMove: true,
            swipe: true,
            touchThreshold: 100,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            responsive: [{breakpoint: 400, settings: {slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1}}, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1}
            }, {breakpoint: 1140, settings: {slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 1}}]
        })
    } catch ($e) {
    }
});
$(function () {
    try {
        $("section.shopping .slider").slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
touchThreshold:1,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            draggable: true,
            touchMove: true,
            touchThreshold: 100,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            responsive: [{breakpoint: 400, settings: {slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1}}, {
                breakpoint: 768,
                settings: {slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1}
            }, {breakpoint: 1140, settings: {slidesToShow: 3, slidesToScroll: 1}}]
        })
    } catch ($e) {
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.fn.customScrollbar) $(".shops-list").customScrollbar();
    selectActiveMapArea()
});
$(document).on("pjax:success", function () {
    selectActiveMapArea()
});

function selectActiveMapArea() {
    if ($(".map svg") !== undefined) {
        $(".map svg a").on("click", function (e) {
            $.pjax({container: "#p0", url: $(this).attr("href")});
            e.preventDefault();
            return false
        });
        if ($("h1").attr("data-shop-id") !== undefined) {
            $(".map svg a[data-shop-id=" + $("h1").attr("data-shop-id") + "] polygon").addClass("active")
        }
    }
}

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    var body = $("body"), position;
    if (body.attr("data-parallax") === undefined) body.attr("data-parallax", body.css("background-position-y"));
    position = parseInt(body.attr("data-parallax")) - parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) / 5;
    body.css({"background-position-y": position})
});
$(document).on("click", ".search", function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        if ($(e.target).attr("name") !== "search") {
            if ($(this).find("input").val() === "") {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                $("nav .mini-logo").removeClass("hide")
            } else $(this).closest("form").submit()
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("nav .mini-logo").addClass("hide")
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    stickyNavTop = $("nav").offset().top - 15;
    stickyNav();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        stickyNav()
    });
    $["ui"]["autocomplete"].prototype["_renderItem"] = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append(item.label).appendTo(ul)
    }
});
var stickyNavTop;

function stickyNav() {
    var header = $("header");
    var logo = $(".logo > a > img");

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop) {
        header.css({height: header.innerHeight()});
        $("nav").addClass("sticky");
        logo.hide();
        $(".c").addClass("container");
        if (window.innerWidth > 766)
        {
            $('.navbars').addClass('navbar-reverse content-center');
            $('.second').addClass('auto-width');
            $('.actions').addClass('display-none');
            // let elem = document.querySelector("rect[data-shop-id='" + document.querySelector("h1[data-shop-id]").getAttribute("data-shop-id") + "']");
            // if (elem === null)
            // {
            //     elem = document.querySelector("polygon[data-shop-id='" + document.querySelector("h1[data-shop-id]").getAttribute("data-shop-id") + "']");
            // }
            // elem.setAttribute("stroke", "red");
        }
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
        logo.show();
        $(".c").removeClass("container");
        if (window.innerWidth > 766)
        {
            $('.navbars').removeClass('navbar-reverse content-center');
            $('.second').removeClass('auto-width');
            $('.actions').removeClass('display-none');
        }
    }
    
}
```

```css
#w1 {display:block !important}
```

Comment: сейчас проверью и отпишусь

Comment: но вы сказали убрать variableWidth:true а у вас стоит true ничего не убрано почему так?

Comment: @Demon__ANT что значит не убрано, вы не в ту функцию смотрите. `$("section.shopping .slider")` отвечает за 3.

Comment: спасибо огромное вам.Принял ответ дал награду и плюсанул :)